# create a trigger for getting client ip address into column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, toad

```
CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `prj_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prj_name` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `prj_customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prj_url` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `prj_description` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `prj_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prj_member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prj_crtd_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `prj_crtd_dt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `prj_updt_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `prj_updt_dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `prj_last_ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prj_id`),
  KEY `fk_project_customer_customer_id` (`prj_customer_id`),
  KEY `fk_project_member_member_id` (`prj_member_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_project_customer_customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`prj_customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`cus_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_project_member_member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`prj_member_id`) REFERENCES `member` (`mem_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to create trigger for three columns for this table project. I want to create trigger for columns of `prj_crtd_dt`, which insert the date when it is created, `prj_updt_dt` which insert the date when it is updated, `prj_last_ip` which has to update the ip address of the system from where it is created.

I have created trigger for the date column and I want to know how to create for ip address

`CREATE TRIGGER create_date_of_customer BEFORE INSERT ON customer
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.cus_crtd_dt = NOW();
    NEW.cus_updt_dt = NOW();`

Comment: Slightly more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not illustrated. However according to my understanding the follwing will help you. Have you seen https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx?

**EDITED**

This for your edited question.For getting the IPAddress you have to enable the cmdshell. However, Enabling xp_cmdshell has security drawbacks and I won't advise you on doing so. If you can use servername instead of server IP then try this,

```
SET NEW.cus_crtd_dt = NOW();
    NEW.cus_updt_dt = NOW();
    NEW.cus_last_ip= SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName');
```

or this,

```
SET NEW.cus_crtd_dt = NOW();
    NEW.cus_updt_dt = NOW();
    NEW.cus_last_ip= @@SERVERNAME;
```

Comment: You can mention this in the comment instead of answer ;)

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER create_date_of_customer BEFORE INSERT ON people
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.peo_crtd_dt = NOW();
    NEW.peo_updt_by = NOW();
    NEW.peo_last_ip= SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName');
Static Analysis
1 errors were found during analysis.

    Unrecognized statement type. (near "NEW" at position 0)

SQL query:

NEW.peo_updt_by = NOW()

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NEW.peo_updt_by = NOW()' at line 1

Comment: Can you help out with this thing @Suraz