# Mysql trigger for logging with referer

Tags: mysql, logging, triggers, referer

I am trying to implement a logger that logs all inserts, updates and deletes on a specific table.

For this I use the simple way described here: https://www.jicdesign.com/blog/3964-2/

Is there an option to log the triggering PHP script (scriptname) or the IP address of the call as well? I would like to be able to make the conclusion: This script (or this IP address) made the following change at a certain point in time: xxxxx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41356702/575376

Comment: You can try to get the IP address of the client as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263453/retrieve-client-ip-address-in-mysql). But this means the client for the MySQL server which would be the machine hosting the web server your PHP script runs in, not the client of said web server.